# Configurar path/url en service

Tags: angular

Tengo el siguiente servicio

```
save(data: any) : Observable<any> {
  return this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/myapp/period/save', data);
}

delete(id: number) {
  return this.http.delete('http://localhost:8080/myapp/period/delete2?id=' + id);
}
```

Me gustaria configurar el path: "http://localhost:8080/myapp/" pero a nivel general, ya que muchos servicios usarán esta url

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear un fichero, por ejemplo **constantes.ts** en el que colocar aquellos valores constantes, por ejemplo:

```
export const url_base = "http://localhost:8080/myapp/";
```

y en cada servicio que vayas a utilizarlo lo importas

```
import {url_base} from './constantes.ts';
```

Luego lo usarías así

```
save(data: any) : Observable<any> {
  return this.http.post(url_base + 'period/save', data);
}

delete(id: number) {
  return this.http.delete(url_base + 'period/delete2?id=' + id);
}
```

Si vas a usar una url para desarrollo y otra para producción (que sería lo lógico), sólo tendrás que cambiar esa constante.

También puedes usar los ficheros **environment.ts** y **environment.pro.ts** que ya tendrían en cuenta en qué entorno estás trabajando.

Comment: tengo una duda, para mis pruebas uso http://localhost:4200/ pero cuando realmente pase a PROD lo que hago es ng build --output-hashing none, eso me genera los archivos .js y los copio al proyecto base, que puede estar en http://localhost:8080/myapp/ o http://localhost:8090/myapp/, no se como aplicarlo

Comment: Cuando estás en desarrollo, configura la constante como **export const url_base = "localhost:4200"** y cuando vayas a compilar para producción lo haces con **export const url_base = "localhost:8080/myapp"** o **export const url_base = "localhost:8090/myapp"**. Las dos a la vez no puede ser, salvo que implementes una estrategia de comprobar si el servidor está escuchando, pero eso es más complejo.

Comment: entiendo, el problema es que en prod nunca sabre cuál es la url, por lo que automaticamente deberia coger la url de la APP base

Comment: No, lo que te he comentado en el comentario anterior es para hacer el cambio manualmente. Como te comento en la respuesta general, también puedes utilizar los ficheros **environment.ts** y **environment.pro.ts** y al generar el deployment incluir en el comando configuration=production, entonces, en el primer fichero pondrías la constante de desarrollo y en el segundo la de producción.